# elasticsearch: running a script over top hits aggregation fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to perform a terms aggregation and in every results bucket get the hit fields after a script manipulation was performed.

For example, if these are the documents:

```
{"age": 15, "firstName": "Dana", "lastName": "Miller"}
{"age": 15, "firstName": "Michelle", "lastName": "Bob"}
{"age": 32, "firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Smith"}
{"age": 32, "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Taylor"}
```

The aggregation is by the "age" field, and the script is:
"return 'doc['firstName'] + ' ' + doc['lastName']"

The results should be:

bucket 1 (age: 15):

- "Dana Miller"
- "Michelle Bob"

Buchet 2 (age 32):

- Mary Smith
- Anna Taylor

Is this possible in elasticsearch?

**EDIT**:

In addition, I'm looking for a way to run a script over multiple hits in a bucket.
For example, if we use the documents above and the terms aggregation by the age field, can I get the results of the hits in the bucket together in the following way?

Bucket 1 (age 15):

- "Dana Miller and Michelle Bob"

Bucket2 (age 32):

- "Mary Smith and Anna Taylor"

Is it possible in ES?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Following Query can help you.

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "group By age": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "age"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "top hits": {
           "top_hits": {
              "script_fields": {
                 "Name": {
                    "script": "doc['firstName'].value + ' ' + doc['lastName'].value "
                  }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
      }
   }
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thank you. can you also run a script over multiple buckets?

Comment: Your answer helped. I also added to the question above another question: run a script over the results of multiple buckets. For example, get the following result for bucket 1: "Dana Miller and Michelle Bob".

Comment: I'm sorry: run a script over multiple hits in a bucket (not multiple buckets).